# Excel : Check in which range is a specific value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I make two sheets : one called 'Result' which tracks values between 0 and 100 and another one called 'range' which display a value if a result!value is in a specific range (0-14, 15-19, 20-24, ..., 76-80, 81-85, 86-100). On the 'range' sheet, I want to display the value linked to the correct 'result!value' range.

For instance, if range!value for 61-65 is 43, the formula should say 43 if result!value is between 61-65 (61,65 included).

I created the following formula, which works perfectly but is pretty ugly :

```
=if(AND(Result!G3>85,Result!G3<100),C$61, if(AND(Result!G3>80,Result!G3<86),C$62,if(AND(Result!G3>75,Result!G3<81),C$63,if(AND(Result!G3>70,Result!G3<76),C$64,if(AND(Result!G3>65,Result!G3<71),C$65,if(AND(Result!G3>60,Result!G3<66),C$66,if(AND(Result!G3>55,Result!G3<61),C$67,if(AND(Result!G3>50,Result!G3<56),C$68,if(AND(Result!G3>44,Result!G3<50),100-C$68,if(AND(ResultG3>39,Result!G3<45),100-C$67,if(AND(Result!G3>34,Result!G3<40),100-C$66,if(AND(Result!G3>29,Result!G3<35),100-C$65,if(AND(Result!G3>24,Result!G3<30),100-C$64,if(AND(Result!G3>19,Result!G3<25),100-C$63,if(AND(Result!G3>14,Result!G3<20),100-C$62,100-C$61)))))))))))))))
```

The basic element from this formula is :

```
if(AND(Result!G3>x,Result!G3<y),range!value,if(AND(Result!G3>x-5,Result!G3<range!y-5))
```

With `x=80` and `y=86` (but the 86-100 range). When `x>50`, range!value becomes `100-range!value` if 71-75 sends 43, 25-29 sends (100-43) = 57.

It checks every range then send the result if TRUE or try the following range is FALSE. I'm looking for a nicer and maybe shorter solution to my problem.

Comment: look into VLOOKUP(), it does right what you want.

Comment: VLOOKUP() needs an additional specific table for it, right ? Three columns : one for the min.value (included), one for the max. value (excluded) and one for the value to use. Is that right ?

Comment: No, VLOOKUP() can use a (sorted) table with _two_ column, it interprets the first column as the cutting points. That assumes you have neither overlapping ranges nor holes, but that's typically the case. Having your cutoff points in a table is a clearer way than burying them inside the formula anyway; and you can put that table on a separate (even _hidden_) sheet, if you want them out of sight.

Comment: either VLOOKUP or MATCH probably will help you, please post some sample data, without that it's difficult to advice anything more specific

Comment: agreed.. need sample data to assist.